# Declaring date variable

Tags: sql-server, date, declare

I want to declare a start and end date using the following:

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME = '2019-05-08'
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME = '2019-05-14'
```

and then use this in a `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
WHERE dc.Date >= @start_date AND dc.Date < @end_date
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

**Error converting data type varchar to float. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)**

Can anyone help me understand this error please?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

Note that the following works:

```
WHERE dc.Date >= '2019-05-08' AND dc.Date < '2019-05-14'
```

**EDIT**

The full query is:

```
DECLARE @unit_id INT = {unit_id}
DECLARE @location_id INT = {location_id}
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME = '{start_date}'
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME = '{end_date}'

   SELECT dc.Date AS timestamps, COALESCE(ud.SalesQty, 0.0) AS quantities
     FROM DIM.DayCalendar AS dc WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN FACT.UnitData AS ud
           ON dc.DayCalendarID = ud.DayCalendarID
          AND ud.UnitID = @unit_id
          AND ud.LocationID = @location_id
    WHERE dc.Date >= @start_date AND dc.Date < @end_date
    ORDER BY timestamps DESC
```

Comment: Sounds like your column `dc.Date` is a `float`; if so, why?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks but when printing the first row of that column, I get: `dc.Date = 2019-05-13 00:00:00`

Comment: Could you paste the whole query?

Comment: Then `WHERE dc.Date >= @start_date AND dc.Date < @end_date` isn't causing the error; it's coming from somwhere else. If `dc.Date` has a value like `2019-05-13 00:00:00` then it's either a `smalldatetime` or a `datetime2(0)`, and `datetime` is neither a `varchar` or `float`. Meaning that the error isn't in the snippet we have.

Comment: Share your total Query.

Comment: I think you should be tagging the programming language your using. `DECLARE @unit_id INT = {unit_id}` isn't valid T-SQL.

Comment: Can you post the DDL of your tables as well?

Comment: hi you can try ISNULL(ud.SalesQty, 0.0) AS quantities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find that `ud.SalesQty` is an `NVARCHAR` column.

You are trying to set the `quantities` field to `0.0` (a float) when the value is `NULL` for `ud.SalesQty`.

Try changing to `0.0` to `'0.0'` or an alternative.

Comment: If this is the case, replacing `COALESCE` with `ISNULL` would avoid the error (as `ISNULL` returns the data type of the first parameter, rather than using data type precedence).

Comment: This raises the question then; why is `SalesQty` a `varchar`, when it clearly should be a numerical data type?